# Markdown editor compatible with multi-level folders or sub-folders?

Tags: markdown, subdirectory

I'm currently using [**Boostnote**](https://boostnote.io/) to manage my code snippets & notes for web development. It's a very interesting open source markdown editor for Mac, Windows and Linux app. However, I'm missing one critical feature in my opinion : `mutli-level folders`, or at least `sub-folders`. I tried to use **Visual Studio Code** with [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles) instead but isn't as fluid as Boostnote!

Does anyone have any other software/tool recommendation?

Comment: If this is still the case, which boostnote are you using ? In any case, both boostnote legacy and boostnote.next  have ability to organize the notes in folders, subfolders and subsubfolders etc. On disc, the files are organized automatically, so you have to export to a tree of md files on demand. This is fairly trivial with both of them.

Comment: I just checked their website and you are right! It wasn't available a year ago (boostnote.next didn't exist) but it looks like they've made some great improvements. I'm curious to try it as it can be a good alternative to Notion, especially for privacy (if you don't use their cloud of course) @MyICQ

Comment: I do not use their cloud, and I really hope they soon bring back some of the great features from "legacy" boostnote.